# What browser is used by android App with an iFrame

Tags: android, ios, iframe, browser, stripe-payments

I'm developping a mobile app in Ionic 5 cordova, and in my app I use an iFrame.

I would need to know what browser is used in Android and in ios.

I ask that because I'm using Stripe Payment Request Button in a webpage embed by iFrame and the button is shown when I open the app as a PWA, but not when it is build as an android/ios application.

When I look at the requirements for the Payment Request Button to work, it say that I need a browser compatible to Gpay/Apple Pay. Since I have the button appearing chrome mobile and on chrome browser, but not when opening as my mobile app, I assume the browser use for an iFrame is not compatible with the Payment button ?

Comment: Possibly related: https://github.com/stripe/stripe-payments-demo/issues/44#issuecomment-570106112 and

Comment: Yeah seems like the situation is exactly that ... The payment request button wont work in an iFrame. 
Do you know if it could work with in-app browser ?

Answer (score 0):

Apple Pay for the Web should be supported in a [SFSafariViewController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariservices/sfsafariviewcontroller) on iOS.

Google Pay for the Web is [not supported in an Android webview](https://developers.google.com/pay/api/web/support/faq):

> For Android apps which use WebViews, you must invoke native Android Google Pay APIs. See [Binding JavaScript code to Android code](https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview#BindingJavaScript) for examples.